# ERROR: Reference the counter as the target of an assignment - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm relatively new to SQL.
I'm trying to print a simple pattern through this code

```
declare
   n number(2):=5;
   temp number(2):=n;
 begin
   for a in 1..5
       a:=a+1;loop
       for b in 1..temp loop
           b:=b+1;
           dbms_output.put_line(' ');
           temp:=temp-1;
       end loop;
   for c in 1..2*a-1 loop
   c:=c+1;
   dbms_output.put_line('*');
 end loop;
end loop;
end;
/
```

I keep getting this error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "A" when expecting one of the following:
* & - + / at loop mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> ||
multiset
```

I understand Oracle doesn't allow to reference the counter as the target of an assignment which is why I keep getting error at line 6 but I'm unable to make it work even by declaring another global variable and assigning increment statement in it but  it doesn't work either.
Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: what do you want the output to be?

Comment: you don't need a:=a+1 nor b:=b+1 in your loop, a and be will be auto incremented when reaching the end loop keyword.

Comment: I'm trying to print Pascal's Triangle

Comment: @StephaneM: If I eliminate the increment a and b statement off my code it just prints 25 rows of straight line *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the previous answers to actually give you Pascal's triangle, which you mentioned you were attempting in a comment:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped
declare
   n number(2):=5;
begin
  for a in 1..n loop
    for b in 1..n-a loop
      dbms_output.put(' ');
    end loop;
    for c in 1..2*a-1 loop
      dbms_output.put('*');
    end loop;
    dbms_output.new_line;
  end loop;
end;
/

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Both your `dbms_output.put_line` calls needed to be just `dbms_output.put`, as that was printing each `*` on a line on its own. But you do need a line break after each time around the `a` loop, so I've added a `dbms_output.newline` at the end of that. You were also decrementing `temp` inside the `b` loop, which meant it was zero instead of `(n-1)` for the second time around the `a` loop; but you don't really need a separate `temp` variable at all as that is always the same as `(n-a)+1` and the `+1` just puts an extra space on every line. (I also made the `a` loop `1..n` as I assume you want to change the value of `n` later in one place only). With `n := 8`:

```
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
***************
```

Crucially though you also have to `set serveroutput on format wrapped`, otherwise the leading spaces you're generating in the `b` loop are discarded.

You can also do this in plain SQL, though you need to supply the `5` twice, or use a bind or substitution variable:

```
select lpad(' ', 5 - level, ' ') || rpad('*', (level * 2) - 1, '*') as pascal
from dual
connect by level <= 5

PASCAL
------------------------------
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Your `b` and `c` loops are just doing a manual `lpad` really.

Comment: That actually helped, Alex. I appreciate it.  The code works fine.

Comment: I was wondering, in terms of processing which one is going to execute faster? Or if anyone know how to find out the execution time of a query or PL/SQL block.

Comment: @RaviTiwari - you can `set timing on` in SQL*Plus, or an SQL Developer worksheet. SQL will be faster than PL/SQL generally but it'll be hard to see the difference here.

Answer (score 1):

When I took your code in my editor I first noticed, you tried to increase a before starting the loop, and Oracle gives first error at that point. And also it does not allow you to increase counter variable in for loop, (I don't know why) I checked on the internet and found that you can not set increment step for Oracle for loops also you can not set a value for counter variable in for loop.

The code below works fine for me :

```
declare
   n number(2):=5;
   temp number(2):=n;
 begin
   for a in 1..5
   loop    --a:=a+1;
       for b in 1..temp loop
           --b:=b+1;
           dbms_output.put_line(' ');
           temp:=temp-1;
       end loop;
   for c in 1..2*a-1 loop
   --c:=c+1;
   dbms_output.put_line('*');
 end loop;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

As StephaneM says, loop variables are incremented by the loop itself: you don't need to do `a := a + 1`, and most of all you CAN'T assign them ! Here is a corrected version:

```
declare
   n number(2):=5;
   temp number(2):=n;
begin
  for a in 1..5
  loop
    for b in 1..temp loop
      dbms_output.put_line(' ');
      temp:=temp-1;
    end loop;
    for c in 1..2*a-1 loop
      dbms_output.put_line('*');
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the desire output. Perhaps there's a flaw in my code? Edit: I'm trying to print Pascal's Triangle