# Print pascal triangle in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

How to print a pascal triangle with '*' in Oracle using Pl/SQL functions, I am expecting to write in minimal lines of code. Can anyone help me ?
This is what I tried,

```
begin
for i in 1..5 loop
dbms_output.put_line('');
for j in 1..i loop
dbms_output.put('*');
end loop;
end loop;
end;
```

I have an answer with two for loops to print a triangle, but I am trying to finish with one for loop using Lpad() and Rpad() functions.

Comment: And, in later news, how to write an accounting package in 8051 assember, an operating system in Object-oriented COBOL, and pretty much _anything_ in Pascal :-)

Comment: You are very welcome to [ask for homework here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). But if doing so, you definitively should show what you have tried so far. Not only this will prove that you are not here in the hope for us to do *your* work. But it also helps to identify your actual level and what could possibly be your true difficulties.

Comment: I've answered this before but you should show what you've already tried and what issues you're having before I link to that; otherwise there's a chance you won't understand or learn from the task. (Easy enough to find my previous answer of course, but please try yourself first!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to show how one can approach a problem logically when one does not have any idea how to proceed.  No one is here to do homework for you, but we can give some pointers on approaching a problem, then help guide when we see what you come up with.

Start with the end result desired and work backward to figure out what to do to get the desired result.  What do you expect the output to be?  Something like this (for 4 rows)?:

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
```

Do you notice a recurring pattern?  "recurring pattern" indicates a loop of some sort will be required.  Perhaps if you replace the leading spaces with another character, another recurring pattern will become obvious:

```
XXX*
XX* *
X* * *
* * * *
```

So, a recurring pattern within another recurring pattern.  What is the relationship between the number of leading spaces to the number of '*'s in the row?  The need for a calculation or two may become apparent, depending on the row.  That is about all I want to give away, as the point of the assignment is for you to figure it out.

Hopefully this provided a nudge on how to approach solving a problem without giving too much away.

**Edit 6/27/2022**
Yeah I know this is old, but since it's been answered I thought it would be fun to do with a recursive CTE query:

```
COLUMN C FORMAT a30;
WITH GenTriangle(TotRows, CurRow, StrOut) AS (
    SELECT 6, 0, NULL FROM dual
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, CurRow + 1, LPAD(' ', TotRows - (CurRow + 1), ' ') || RPAD('*', ((CurRow + 1) * 2) - 1, '*')  
    FROM GenTriangle
    WHERE CurRow + 1 <= TotRows
  )
  SELECT StrOut AS triangle FROM GenTriangle;

TRIANGLE                                                                        
--------------------------------------
                                                                                
     *                                                                          
    ***                                                                         
   *****                                                                        
  *******                                                                       
 *********                                                                      
***********                                                                     

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: Ok thanks Gary for your demonstration of pascal triangle, actually I am expecting to print like first one, but it need to be in odd numbers like 1,3,5,7. and I am expecting the solution in Lpad() and Rpad() PL/SQL functions.

Answer (score 1):

First I try to draw the pascal triangle with three four loops, it works correctly. Here is the answer..

```
Declare
inc number := 4;
BEGIN

FOR Outter IN 1 .. inc LOOP

          FOR Inner IN 1 .. inc - Outter   LOOP
            dbms_output.put(' ');
          END LOOP;

          FOR Inner IN 1 .. Outter   LOOP
            dbms_output.put('*');
          END LOOP;          

    dbms_output.put_line(' ');

END LOOP;

END;
```

This is an anonymous block in PL/SQL, and I have an answer with one four loop as well, which correctly print pascal triangle as I expected.

```
DECLARE 
  row_num_ NUMBER := 5; 
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN 0..row_num_ LOOP 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ' || LPAD(' ', row_num_ - i, ' ') || RPAD('*', 2 * i - 1, '*')); 
    END LOOP;  
END;
```

Thank you friends for your great support..

Comment: [You can do it in plain SQL as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22715832/266304).

Comment: OK thanks Alex, I like the answer in this                        [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713670/error-reference-the-counter-as-the-target-of-an-assignment-pl-sql/22715832#22715832). as well..

Comment: That's the same answer (of mine!) that I linked to *8-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare
n number;
BEGIN
n:=&n;
FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP


      FOR j IN 1 .. i   LOOP
        dbms_output.put('* ');
      END LOOP;          

    dbms_output.put_line(' ');

END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give some explanation as to *WHY* you answer is the one.

Answer (score 0):

How to get pyramid shape by using procedure?
The following code can achieve that:

```
declare
    s2 varchar2(38);
    s3 varchar2(38);
    m number(10):=6;
    l number(10);
    s1 varchar2(38);
    a varchar2(38);
    b varchar2(38);
begin
    l:=((m*2)/2)+1;
    for r in 0..m
    loop
        s2:=trim(both ' ' from s3)||' '||r;
        a:=lpad(s2,l+r+1,'*')||' '||'';
        b:=rpad(a,(m*2)+r+1,'*');
        s1:=b;
        dbms_output.put_line(s1);
        s3:=trim(both '*' from s1);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

We will then get this result:

```
****** 0 ****
******0 1 ****
*****0 1 2 ****
****0 1 2 3 ****
***0 1 2 3 4 **** 
**0 1 2 3 4 5 ****
*0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ****
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare v_str varchar2(10) := '*'

begin
   for i in 1..5 loop
      v_str:= rpad(v_str, i, '*');
      dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
   end loop;
end;
```

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```